Investigating timeout in Karafka server: CPU utilisation, Memory utilisation, max.poll.interval.ms
I have a rails application, which includes an API server(rails server) and Worker server(Karafka server).
From the API server we send some messages to topic T1 (has just 1 partition), now the Worker server consumes this message, based on this we fetch a file(this will have a header row followed by rows of values, around 500,000 records) from SFTP, now after some processing we save each record in the file to DB and send these records to topic T2 (has 10 partitions). Now the Worker server again consumes from this topic, process each records further and send to a destination topic T3.
This is the overall working of the application. We're using multiple instances for the Worker server for parallel processing (Note that parallel processing is useful while consuming message from T2).
Now in production an issue occurred, one message in the T1 consumer got timed out and Karafka retried again. I needed to know why the time out happened, so i tested the same situation in the lower env, but couldn't replicate the scenario. The max.poll.interval.ms in the Karafka config is set to a decent amount and the time out happened before this internal. I can't see any error logs too in production. I checked the system resource utilisation on newrelic for the lower env. The CPU utilisation is 100% for the Worker server for several minutes, the max memory utilisation is 30%. In the lower env, every steps got successfully processed.
My doubt is, if it's not because of the max.poll.interval.ms, what caused this time out, can it be because of the 100% CPU utilisation? Initially my assumption was it got timed out due to memory limit hit.
rails version: 7.0.8.1,
karafka version: 2.1.11
Please let me know if any other details are required. Thank you.

I'm not sure what you mean by saying "timeout". Karafka has many timeouts and first, what we should establish is whether you are talking about:

wait timeout in producer
Broker transport failure (transport)
Maximum poll interval timeout
Network exception
or something entirely different

You are not clear about this.
Every single error that originates from Karafka has a description and is of a certain class. Error log should have an exact explanation of what happened.
Now for the rest of your question:

I needed to know why the time-out happened

Check logs.

I can't see any error logs too in production

Karafka logs every single error to the same pipeline. If you cannot locate the error, it means your error tracking is incorrect.

Can it be because of the 100% CPU utilization?

If your CPU is always fully utilized, weird things may happen with Karafka. Same with most of the other software. Karafka is a multi-threaded software that runs many things under the hood. Many timeouts related to sockets, etc., may have kicked in. Nonetheless, logs should have it. If they don't, it is either what I have mentioned, which is poor logging, or the fact that the machine got overloaded to a point where logs would not be stored.
Also, please remember that you're running an outdated version of Karafka. 2.1.1 when there is already 2.4.0 with many fixes and improvements.
